# Why does loading tikz before calling "driver=dvips" make a difference

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pstricks

This question doesn't entirely make sense because I know I don't need to call `driver=dvips`.  But I would like to know whether anyone can explain what's happening.

*A little background*

I'm trying to learn `tikz`.  So, I decided to take some old documents containing---what I thought were simple---graphics I created using `pstricks` and rewrite them using `tikz`.

Being a creature of habit, I was going the `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` (I have a shell script which handles this.  So, this is usually very unconscious on my part.)  But then I was trying things with `tikz` (such as using `spy`) which didn't seem to like this route.  I remembered I should just being using `pdflatex` with `tikz`.

Also, I'd forgotten about some of the other bells-and-whistles I normally load to get `pstricks` to work correctly:  one of which was to load the driver `dvips`.

So this is what I noticed:

If I compile (using `pdflatex`) this first MWE, everything works quite well---even though I'm calling the driver `dvips`.  (The `tikz` code is from van Dongen's new book.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[driver=dvips,
            landscape,
            twocolumn,
           ]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [spy using outlines={circle,
                         magnification=2.5,
                         size=3cm,
                         connect spies}]
    \begin{scope}
    [spy using outlines={circle,
                         magnification=3,
                         size=3.5cm,
                         red,
                         connect spies}]
    \draw (-36:0.8)
          \foreach \angle in {0,36,...,359}{
                -- (\angle:0.8)
                   (\angle:1.1) node {$\angle$}
                   (0,0) -- (\angle:0.8)
            };
        \spy on (167:1) in node (zoom) at (-30:5.5);
    \end{scope}
    \spy[blue] on (zoom) in node [right] at (-135:4.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

But I was sloppy with loading packages once and got frustrated that my `landscape` directive to `geometry` seemed to be ignored in the final pdf document.

Here's the MWE for this **fail** where the only difference with the previous MWE is when I call `\usepackage{tikz}`.  (Still compiling using `pdflatex`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[driver=dvips,
            landscape,
            twocolumn,
           ]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [spy using outlines={circle,
                         magnification=2.5,
                         size=3cm,
                         connect spies}]
    \begin{scope}
    [spy using outlines={circle,
                         magnification=3,
                         size=3.5cm,
                         red,
                         connect spies}]
    \draw (-36:0.8)
          \foreach \angle in {0,36,...,359}{
                -- (\angle:0.8)
                   (\angle:1.1) node {$\angle$}
                   (0,0) -- (\angle:0.8)
            };
        \spy on (167:1) in node (zoom) at (-30:5.5);
    \end{scope}
    \spy[blue] on (zoom) in node [right] at (-135:4.5);


\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

There are no problems if I get rid of the `driver=dvips` call.  So, please no explanations that I don't need that driver.  But what I would like to know is: why there's only an apparent conflict with the driver if `tikz` is called before I call the driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you load `geometry` with the faulty `dvips` driver then it doesn't set the lengths responsable for the "pdf-background" `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` and so they keep their default value (set today normally in the format). In my case this is a4 portrait (even if I add some paper option like `letterpaper`).

If you additionally load `tikz` it will load `graphicx` which in turn will set `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` to the current values of `\paperwidth` and `paperheight` – which are before `geometry` in your example "letterpaper portrait" and after `geometry` "letterpaper landscape".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `tikz` most likely also specifies what driver it wants to use in a semi-automatic way. From what I can see, its  probably selecting `pdftex`.

So what is happening is the following:

`Fail: Load Tikz -> driver=pdftex -> Load Geometry -> driver=dvips`

`Success: Load Geometry -> driver=dvips -> Load Tikz -> driver=pdftex`

Since the code works in the second case, it is likely that the dvips driver messes up a page setting in some way, which affects the end result. For instance, if you change in the second answer `driver=dvips` to `driver=pdftex`, it works fine.

In short, the main issue is that both packages specify the driver to use in some way, which is why the order matters for the result. This also depends on what processor you use (pdflatex, etc) since they expect different drivers to be used for correct results.